# System.console() with file input

Tags: java, console

I would like to make use of [`java.io.Console`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html). I am trying to do so by invoking [`System.console()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29). This works..some of the time.

This is fine when I run my program like so:

```
java classn
```

However, I would like to read standard input from a file named `input.in`. When I try to do so via:

```
java classn < input.in
```

I receive a null pointer exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at classn.main(classn.java:9)
```

Is there a fix so I can use `Console` along with input from a fix? I realise why it's returning null, I would just like to know if there's a way to hook the `Console` into what's being passed in via a file.

Comment: Can you post the source of classn so we can help diagnose the problem a little further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you'd have to test whether `System.console()` returned null. If it did, you'd have to work without an interactive console - there's no getting around that. You can use `System.in` to get the information from the redirected file.

An alternative is to have a command-line option to read appropriate data from the given filename, but then interact with the console for the rest.

Comment: But is there a good reason why `System.console()` would be null and `System.in` not be? Why was it designed like that? I believe it would be because it uses platform independent ways to suppress input (ex: `readPassword()`), but can you confirm this?

Comment: @Tim: System.console is designed to return an *interactive* console, with both read and write capabilities. If you're redirecting input, you don't get that.

Comment: in theory (at least on UNIX), System.console could open "/dev/tty".

Answer (score 2):

Often, the easyest way is to use the Scanner class, bounded to System. in:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
```

Call your program

```
 cat foo | java Sample
```

on linux/unix/bsd, or

```
 type foo | java Sample
```

on Windows.